# The mapped network drive could not be created because the following error has occurred: The parameter is incorrect

Tags: ntlm, windows-server-2016, network-drive, cifs, fileshare

cmd.exe /C "cmdkey /add:`"******`" /user:`"*****" /pass:`"**********`""

[OS version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZnuL.png)

[Share Disk mount Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EgAsT.jpg)

1.Checked the network connection no block
2.Checked the smb client version smb2.

3.Capture the packet.
[Screenshot of the packet capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QjDjD.png)

Answer (score 1):

After I did some research I found the LAN Manager authentication level will leading the error of the authentication.

[MS DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/network-security-lan-manager-authentication-level)

Then I delete this HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\LmCompatibilityLevel in my Registry Editor and tried again it successfully mount the network drive.